# How to calculate percentage for sum of difference of two columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns in the same table, that needs to be summed and get the difference and then calculate the percentage?

```
SELECT sum([BillCount]) - sum([IssueCount]) as [Difference]
FROM Invoice
where [Year] = '2015'
```

In the above query I got the result for the difference as 244234. Now I need to calculate the percentage by dividing the difference with the actual Billcount 260918.

sample Data:

```
SELECT sum(BillCount) as bills, sum(IssueCount) as issues
FROM Invoice
where [Year] = '2015'
```

Result:
    Bills: 260918
    Issues: 16684
    Difference: 244234
    Divide Difference By actual Bills: 244234/260918 = 0.93
    Percentage: 0.93*100 = 93.60

I have used the changed divisor from zero to one. But I am getting the percentage result in many rows, like for each individual billcount. Is there any way that I could get the exact percentage in one row like we calculate in calculator?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
SELECT sum([BillCount]) - sum([IssueCount]) as [Difference],
    (sum(IssueCount) - sum(BillCount)) / nullif(sum(BillCount), 0) as ptcdiff
FROM Invoice
where [Year] = '2015'
```

You'll note I changed the order of subtraction. This makes it so that its a negative change rather than a positive change. If you need an absolute. change, you can just throw abs() around the result. You can also bake this into a function if it makes sense to

```
declare 
    @pctOld float = 260918,
    @pctNew float = 16684  

select PctDiff = case when @PctNew is null or @PctOld is null then null
                       when @PctNew = null or @PctOld = null then null
                       when @PctNew = 0 and @PctOld = 0 then 0    
                       when @PctNew = 0 and @PctOld > 0 then -100.00
                       when @PctNew >= 0 and @PctOld < 0 then null
                       when @PctNew < 0 and @PctOld > 0 then null
                       when @PctOld = 0 then null
                       else ((@PctNew - @PctOld) / abs(@PctOld)) * 100.0
                  end
```

Comment: need one more set of parentheses, and can't divide by zero, change default divisor to 1:    `SELECT sum([BillCount]) - sum([IssueCount]) as [Difference],
    (sum(IssueCount) - sum(BillCount)) / nullif(BillCount, 1)
`

Comment: Can I get total percentage? i.e., total percentage for all the Billcount? @Xedni

Comment: @Xedni, I changed the default divisor from zero to one.

Comment: I have used the changed divisor from zero to one. But I am getting the percentage result in many rows, like for each individual billcount. Is there any way that I could get the exact percentage in one row like we calculate in calculator?

Comment: @CharlesBretana It wasn't a default; it was to protect against a div by zero error.

Comment: @user7463647 i'm not sure what you mean between "total percentage" and "total percentage for all the Billcount". Can you elaborate a bit? Do you just mean breaking it down at a different granularity? If so, you can add a `group by` clause at the granularity you need.

Comment: If I use this query: SELECT sum([BillCount]) - sum([IssueCount]) as [Difference],
    (sum([IssueCount]) - sum([BillCount])) / nullif([BillCount], 1) as ptcdiff
FROM Invoice
where [Year] = '2015'
group by [BillCount], [IssueCount]..... I am getting 884 rows, Is it possible to get exact percentage? @xedni

Comment: @user7463647 you're getting 884 rows because that's how many distinct combinations of BillCount and IssueCount there are. Remember the columns immediately following the `group by` are how you want SQL to chunk up your aggregates (sum in this case). Try *removing* your group by. That will group over the entire table

Comment: Do you mean to remove group by function in the query? If I do so I am getting an Error Msg 8120 SQL: Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause. @Xedni

Comment: @user7463647 I had a typo in my code sample. All columns that aren't in the group by have to be in aggregates, and the denominator had `BillCount` instead of `sum(BillCount)`. I've corrected that. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your current expression with `SUM([BillCount])` aggregated value

Something like this

```
select (sum([BillCount]) - sum([IssueCount])) / NULLIF(sum([BillCount]),0) * 100
FROM Invoice
where [Year] = '2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

Subquery like this

```
Select Difference/nullif(sum(BIllCount), 1) From (SELECT sum([BillCount]) - sum([IssueCount]) as [Difference],
FROM Invoice
where [Year] = '2015') Per
```